# How to create a form that allows user to enter a variable number of items

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am a total beginner to Microsoft Access 2010. I need a form that allows a user add items from as list to a list. The items can be added until initial list is exhausted.

Here's the most basic example I can give. Lets suppose that two persons attend a car show. As they are leaving, they are asked their name, and what cars they saw. First person saw only two cars. The second one saw fifty cars.

On the form, they would write their name one time (at the top of the page) and then they have to fill the list of cars they saw from the list of all cars. They would not write their name next to each car.

How do I create an equivalent MS Access 2010 form?

Answer (score 0):

You need your answer to be an application - this is too broad.

I try to give basic idea.

You need one form which will be saved to the database each time a person fills the list.

It must contain 1 text box for Persons names. One List with all cars that are on the show and one empty list. And 2 buttons - `cancel` and `save`.

For each new person operator write his name of the person. Then operator selects cars from fisrt list and transfer its to the second. This can be done by double click or by selecting a car and pressing additional button. This must work in the opposite direction too.

Then when pressing `save` button the data will be saved inside database and the form will be reset - first list will contain all cars from the show, second will be empty and text box will be empty.

If operator presses `cancel` button the form will be reset without saving data to database.

You can try serach internet how to implement those lists in MS Access 2010.